# ionic 2: Change value inside <p></p> tag on ion-slide changed

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ionic2

I want to get the current item in `<p>` tag  when each slide change in ionic 2

here is the **HTML file code**:

```
<ion-content>
<ion-slides(ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged()" #mySlider >
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let item of items" (click)="itemClicked($event,item)">
        *<p>{{item.name}}</p>*
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
  <ion-item>
        <p>
*i want to display the item name here on each slide changed*
 </p>
        </ion-item>

</ion-content>
```

can anybody please suggest me how i can do this?

Comment: what about repeating `*ngFor` ?

Comment: *ngFor will display the items in slides in a loop.

Comment: let say we have item "pen" in a slide then that should be displayed in <p> tag inside <ion-item>... when we change the slide the item changes to "pencil" then again the <p> tag should display "pencil" instead of "pen" ... this is all i want!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `slideChangedFunction` you can do:

```
slideChanged() {
  let currentIndex = this.slides.getActiveIndex();
  //with the current index you can retrieve the name from the items array
  var currentName=items[0]["name"];
}
```

and display the `currentName` property in your HTML.
Hope it helps.

- Edit:
  as comments explain, the `currentName` variable should be a class variable, and you have to refer to it using `this.currentName`, so you can show it in HTML

Comment: This will not work. You need to define `currentName` as global variable. Then, do `this.currentName = items[0]["name"]`. Then only in `<p>{{currentName}}</p>` will appear correctly.

Comment: @SagarKulkarni you mean class variable. global would be outside the class .

Comment: Yes, obviously as a class variable or you could not visualize it

Comment: Yeah, I meant class variable.